# Question that is really two questions, but one is a duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169019/differences-between-initializing-arraylist-with-and-without-generics-java#29169019) just came up, which asks two related questions about java ArrayLists.  Some user(s) flagged the question as a duplicate because they found a duplicate for one of the two questions.  But the other question is still unresolved.

The OP even edited the answer to emphasize that only one of his questions was a duplicate:

> Before saying that its a [duplicate], please read the whole question, I have two seperate questions and your link provides answer only for one of them.

What is the proper way to handle this situation?  Some potential actions I've thought are possible:

- Answer both parts of the question (even though the first portion is a duplicate).
- Answer only the non-duplicate part.  Edit (or ask OP to edit) the question to remove the duplicate portion.
- Downvote (lack of research) and move on
- Flag as duplicate
- Flag as too broad

Comment: I would say "Too Broad", since there are two questions there. Each question post should only have one question asked, and the two questions, while both about ArrayLists, are not well related. At least, not to the point that it would warrant both of them in one question. A downvote is entirely up to you.

Comment: I was going to say that the second option would be a reasonable goal while closing "too broad" could be a means toward that goal as opposed to being a permanent outcome (i.e. closing it and leaving it), but seeing the OP spout foreign language in response to the comments makes me not want to offer any sympathy.

Comment: @BoltClock I like that approach.  In the meantime, would removing the duplicate portion be an acceptable edit to make?  That seems  invasive, but on the flipside the duplicate was actually answered and confirmed by the OP.

Comment: If the non-duplicate portion is worth answering I'd say save it by removing the excess growth while you still can. But if no value is lost by closing and/or removing it, I'd say don't waste your time on it.

Comment: @BoltClock that seems reasonable.  Since the other question seems like the kind of question to have already been asked I think I'll abandon ship.